php ffmpeg cannot save video to system temporary folder
I am trying to covert a video to h.264 format. I can save the new video to a normal directory but saving the new video to a Windows temp file fails. However I can manage to save a snapshot image from the video into Windows temp folder without problem. I cannot figure out what is the problem?
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../vendor/autoload.php');

function get_ffmpeg_exe_path_arr_def(){ 
  return( array( 'ffmpeg.binaries'  => "C:/bin/ffmpeg.exe",
                 'ffprobe.binaries' => "C:/bin/ffmpeg.exe",
                 'timeout' => 3600000000, 'ffmpeg.threads' => 12
                )   )  ;  
}

$vid_inp = 'C:/Users/Jordan/Downloads/motorboat_org.mp4' ; 
$vid_out = 'C:/Users/Jordan/Downloads/motorboat_9.mp4' ;
$tmp_vid_out_file = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), "Vid") ; //C:\Windows\Temp\VidA318.tmp 
$tmp_img_file = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), "Img") ; //C:\Windows\Temp\ImgA234.tmp


$ffmpeg = FFMpeg\FFMpeg::create( get_ffmpeg_exe_path_arr_def() );
$video = $ffmpeg->open($vid_inp);
$format = new FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264('aac', 'libx264');

$video->frame(FFMpeg\Coordinate\TimeCode::fromSeconds(0.2))->save($tmp_img_file);
// Ok to save snapshot image to  C:\Windows\Temp\ImgA234.tmp 

$video->save($format, $vid_out); 
// This is ok to save video to  C:/Users/Jordan/Downloads/motorboat_9.mp4

$video->save($format, $tmp_vid_out_file); 
// This fails to save new video to   C:\Windows\Temp\VidA318.tmp  



 -------  Error Message -----
    Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Alchemy\BinaryDriver\Exception\ExecutionFailureException' with message 
'ffmpeg failed to execute command "C:\AppServ\www/ecity/bin/windows/ffmpeg.exe" -y -i 
"C:/Users/Jordan/Downloads/motorboat_org.mp4" 
-threads 12 -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -b:v 1000k 
-refs 6 -coder 1 -sc_threshold 40 -flags +loop 
-me_range 16 -subq 7 -i_qfactor 0.71 -qcomp 0.6 
-qdiff 4 -trellis 1 -b:a 128k -pass 1 -passlogfile 
 "C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\ffmpeg-passes66557e75d5e53hbzbo/pass-66557e75d6e0b" C:\Windows\Temp\VidEA8F.tmp: 
Error Output: ffmpeg version 4.3.2-2021-02-27-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2021 
the FFmpeg developers built with gcc 10.2.0 
(Rev6, Built by MSYS2 project) configuration: 
--enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static 
--disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect 
--enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-lzma 
--enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-libsrt 
--enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-li in C:\AppServ\www\ecity\vendor\php-ffmpeg\php-ffmpeg\src\FFMpeg\Media\AbstractVideo.php on line 106


It seems ffmpeg asks for file format and verbal permission to overwrite the system temporary file.
